# Convolutional layer after embedding layer shapes problem in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to train a model that has 3 input channels. Every channel starts with embedding (as lambda) and a convolution next. However, I can't deal with shapes.

```py
# Build network
def swish(x):
    return K.sigmoid(x) * x

def make_model():
    embed_size = 512 #must be 512 for embedding layer

    input_text1 = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
    embedding1 = Lambda(QTEmbedding, output_shape=(embed_size,))(input_text1)
    con11 = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu')(embedding1)
    pool11 = MaxPooling1D(2)(con11)
    con12 = Conv1D(64,3, activation='relu')(pool11)
    pool12 = MaxPooling1D(2)(con12)
    flat1 = Flatten()(pool12)

    input_text2 = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
    embedding2 = Lambda(QBEmbedding, output_shape=(embed_size,))(input_text2)
    con21 = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu')(embedding2)
    pool21 = MaxPooling1D(2)(con21)
    con22 = Conv1D(64,3, activation='relu')(pool21)
    pool22 = MaxPooling1D(2)(con22)
    flat2 = Flatten()(pool22)


    input_text3 = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
    embedding3 = Lambda(AEmbedding, output_shape=(embed_size,))(input_text3)
    con31 = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu')(embedding3)
    pool31 = MaxPooling1D(2)(con31)
    con32 = Conv1D(64,3, activation='relu')(pool31)
    pool32 = MaxPooling1D(2)(con32)
    flat3 = Flatten()(pool32)


    x = Concatenate()([flat1,flat2,flat3])
    x = Dense(512, activation=swish)(x)
    x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Dense(256, activation=swish)(x)
    x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Dense(64, activation=swish, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)

    output = Dense(len(targets),activation='sigmoid',name='output')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=[input_text1,input_text2,input_text3], outputs=[output])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

And I get this error message:

> **ValueError**: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_24: expected
>   ndim=3, found ndim=2.

I've searched around but didn't find a solution specific to this question.
Please don't link me to another LSTM problem with the same error.

I feel like embedding functions might be the problem as they output 2D tensors.

```
def QTEmbedding(x):
  results = qa.signatures['question_encoder'](tf.squeeze(tf.cast(x, tf.string)))['outputs']
  return keras.backend.concatenate([results])

def QBEmbedding(x):
  results = general(tf.squeeze(tf.cast(x, tf.string)))
  return keras.backend.concatenate([results])

def AEmbedding(x):
  results = qa.signatures['response_encoder'](input=tf.squeeze(tf.cast(x, tf.string)), context=tf.squeeze(tf.cast(x, tf.string)))['outputs']
  return keras.backend.concatenate([results])
```

And these are the models.

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub

general = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/5")
qa = hub.load('https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-qa/3')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common misunderstanding when using the `Conv1D` layers in Keras. According to the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/), the expected `input_shape` is `(batch, steps, channels)`.

In general for 10 rows with 20 features each, you'll have to reshape your data to (10, 20, 1).

In your case, my guess is that the output from the embedding layer is causing the issue. I think the `output_shape` should be `(1, embed_size, 1)`

Comment: Unfortunately ```(1, embed_size, 1)``` didn't work. Still the same error.

Comment: could you please take a look at embeddings?